# service worker cache progress

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching, cacheapi

I am new to java script as well as to PWA.

I am trying to load all of my contents `images/css/audio/video/.html` into the cache using cache API which i did successfully using https://developers.google.com and other resources.

My question now is:
Soon the contents load into the cache the SW(service worker) should tell that all the contents have been loaded. I tried to loop through the static contents which i want to cache, and tried to use alert but it says

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: alert is not defined

1. **How would SW tell the main page (say index.html) that the contents have been cached without clicking any button or interaction?**
2. And if there is a possibility of the progress bar which can show the progress of loading the contents into the cache?
3. **as well as telling your actual cache capacity is 'this' and after loading the contents left is 'this'**?

Comment: Hey, have you had a look at the `addAll` function? After that your cache should be initiated and in theory you should be able to tell the delta, not sure about a precise loading status, doubt it, since it is a single promise.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/addAll

If you really want a progress bar, consider adding them one by one by using `add` instead of `addAll`. Then you can iterate over the resources

Comment: But it would involve a lot of async handling

Comment: @mchl18 many thanks for your time and effort! I am aware of addAll and add methods they add contents into the cache. i am also aware of client.postMessage as well which sends a message into the console as a reply. My question is **How a service worker can tell/communicate browser that i have finished caching and contents are now available offline?** In other words a service worker should send a message into the browser like an alert or pop-up, caching complete, contents are available for offline browsing! If some one can help please, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a client.postMessage() to the service worker on the 'activate' event (which occurs after caching is complete), and navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message') Fn to your content page index.html or whatever.

Here's code I use:

```
// activate with notification TO DOM (!)
global.addEventListener('activate', event => {
  event.waitUntil(async function() {
    await global.clients.claim();
    delay(5000).then(() => {
      data = 'activated';
      console.log('activate msg => dom: ' + data);
      global.clients.matchAll().then(all => all.map(client => client.postMessage(data)));
    });
  }());
});
```

and on content page script:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('message', function(event) {
  console.log('sw message: ' + event.data);
  if ( event.data === 'activated' ) {
    somefunctions();
  }
});
```

Note global.clients.matchAll() broadcasts the message to everything under control of the service worker, which you might not want.